# Hive getting Null upon multiplying one column with a int or decimal value

Tags: hadoop, null, hive

In hive I  have  an internal table table1

```
desc table1;

col_name        data_type      
id                int
acct_cnt1         bigint
acct_cnt2         bigint

select * from table1;

id   enrl_acct_cnt   unenrl_acct_cnt
27      1           7040
493     1           175
513     1           44
515     3           3810
531     1           1956
```

to load into  an intermediate table - table2

```
export OP_RTO=2
export RUN_ID_VAR=418

hive -e "CREATE TABLE TABLE2_$RUN_ID_VAR  AS SELECT ID,ACCT_CNT1,ACCT_CNT2,  $OP_RTO * ACCT_CNT1  as prod_of_op_ratio_and_acct_cnt1 FROM DBNAME.TABLE1";
```

getting NULL in the last column - prod_of_op_ratio_and_acct_cnt1

```
select * from TABLE2_$RUN_ID_VAR;

id     acct_cnt1   acct_cnt2 prod_of_op_ratio_and_acct_cnt1
27      1           7040            NULL
493     1           175             NULL
513     1           44              NULL
```

Comment: This is not reproducible on Hive 1.2.1.  BTW in your example column names in `describe` and in `select` are different.

Comment: id  acct_cnt1   acct_cnt2
27      1           7040
493     1           175
513     1           44
515     3           3810
531     1           1956